# Behaviour - bindable property

Tags: c#, xamarin, bindable

I've created a behavior for validating email input. Following numerous examples on the web. As you can see my behavior has two bindable properties, one is IsValid and second is ErrorMessage.

On text change, app runs regex validation and without any problem assigns value true/false to IsValid property. But when it tries to assign value to the ErrorMessage property it fires exception:

*The BindableProperty "ErrorMessage" is readonly.*

Does any one have an idea why this happens? Thanks in advance!

```
public class EmailValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    const string emailRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
    @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";

    static readonly BindablePropertyKey IsValidPropertyKey = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(EmailValidatorBehavior), false);

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidProperty = IsValidPropertyKey.BindableProperty;

    static readonly BindablePropertyKey ErrorMessagePropertyKey = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("ErrorMessage", typeof(String), typeof(EmailValidatorBehavior), "");

    public static BindableProperty ErrorMessageProperty = ErrorMessagePropertyKey.BindableProperty;


    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IsValidProperty); }
        private set { base.SetValue(IsValidPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return (string)base.GetValue(ErrorMessageProperty); }
        private set { base.SetValue(ErrorMessageProperty, value); }
    }


    void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {


        IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, emailRegex,        
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
        ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.OldTextValue))
            ErrorMessage = "";
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter email address";
            return;
        }
        if (!IsValid)
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email address";
        else
            ErrorMessage = "";

    }


    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
    }
    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just added one more property of type int and it works without any problem, it's not read only. Can be this related to string properties ????

Comment: There's a complete example for behaviors and email validation; maybe you can compare your code: https://blog.xamarin.com/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thank Krumelur, I had started with that example but wanted to add one more property: ErrorMessage instead to set it on the actual View. The example has only on property

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because you have `private set`, so maybe this would be a solution:

```
`public bool IsValid
{
    get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IsValidProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(IsValidPropertyKey, value); }
}

public string ErrorMessage
{
    get { return (string)base.GetValue(ErrorMessageProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(ErrorMessageProperty, value); }
}`
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. Even with normal set it breaks, but it doesn't break for IsValid event it has private set

Answer (score -1):

Change this line

```
private set { base.SetValue(ErrorMessageProperty, value); }
```

to

```
private set { base.SetValue(ErrorMessagePropertyKey, value); }
```

Comment: Please write an explanation why this solves the problem.